# Partial Fraction and the Integration

Tags: calculus, integration

So I have this question that looks like

$$ \frac{x^3 + 3x^2 - x - 8}{x^2 + x - 6} $$

and first I got the partial fraction so getting

$$ x + 2 + \frac{3x + 4}{x^2 + x -6} $$

but now I'm trying to integrate it and I cannot remember for the life of me how I should integrate the fraction on the end. Please help.

Comment: I may be wrong but should the leading $3x+2$ actually be $x+2$?

Comment: Yes seems that I need to be more careful when tying in my questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Remember that $x^2+x-6=(x-2)(x+3)$.

Now apply the partial fraction decomposition again:

$$\frac{3x+4}{x^2+x-6}=\frac{3x+4}{(x-2)(x+3)}=\frac{A}{x-2}+\frac{B}{x+3}$$

Also, it seems as if your division is not correct:

$$\require{cancel}\frac{x^3 + 3x^2 - x - 8}{x^2 + x - 6}=\color{red}{\cancel{3}}x+2+\frac{3x+4}{x^2+x-6}$$

Comment: Would you believe that I actually have that factorisation on my page here, I just didn't see that I should do the partial fractions again. Don't you just feel stupid sometimes :)

Comment: Yeah seems that's a mistype from an earlier mistake that I have scored out. I have got the correct answer now

Comment: Alright, don't forget to press the accept button! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

$$3x+2+\frac{3x+4}{x^2+x−6} =\\3x+2+\frac{3x+4}{(x-2)(x+3)} =\\
3x+2+\frac{a}{(x-2)}+\frac{b}{(x-2)} =\\
$$now find a,b
$$\frac{a}{(x-2)}+\frac{b}{(x-2)} =\frac{a(x+3)+b(x-2)}{(x-2)(x+3)}=\frac{3x
+4}{(x-2)(x+3)}\\\rightarrow \\(a+b)x=3x\\3a-2b=4\\a=2,b=1\\
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can factor the denominator of the last term and decompose again:

$$\frac{3x+4}{x^2+x-6} = \frac{3x+4}{(x+3)(x-2)} = \frac{1}{x+3} + \frac{2}{x-2}.$$

Can you take it from there?